# Socket.io not able to handle multiple clients javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am working on a node.js app where I am using socket.io to send data to multiple clients but the socket is only able to send data to one client i.e if I open my webpage in two tabs its not working in both the tabs but when I open just 1 tab of webpage it is able to transmit the data.I dont know why? Can someone help,Here's my code:

server.js

```
var http = require("http"),
  io = require("socket.io"),
  fs = require("fs"),
  util = require("util");

var backlog_size = 2000;
var filename = process.argv[2];
if (!filename) return util.puts("Usage: node <server.js> <filename>");
var linesCount = 0;
// -- Node.js HTTP Server ----------------------------------------------------------
server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.url)
  filePath = req.url
  if(filePath=="/"){
  filePath='./index.html'
  fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading ' + filePath);
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
  }
else
{
  if(filePath=="/client"){
       filePath = './client.html';
  fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading ' + filePath);
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}}
});
server.listen(8000, "0.0.0.0");
var fsTimeout
var textToSend=""
// -- Setup Socket.IO ---------------------------------------------------------
var socket = io(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
});
socket.on("connection", function (client) {
    
  fs.watchFile(filename, function (curr, prev) {
    
    console.log("file changed");
  
    if (prev.size > curr.size) return { clear: true };
    
    if(!fsTimeout){
    if(prev.ctime.getTime() != curr.ctime.getTime())
    {
      console.log("file changed")
      var stream = fs.createReadStream(filename, {
        start: prev.size,
        end: curr.size,
      });
      stream.on("data", function (lines) {
        console.log(lines.toString());
        textToSend+=lines.toString();
        textlen=textToSend.split("\n").length;
        // count=lines.toString().split("\n").length
        // linesCount += count;
        // console.log(linesCount);
        console.log(textlen)
        if(textlen<10)
           { 
            console.log("me") 
            client.emit("tail", { lines: lines.toString("utf-8").split("\n") });}
        else 
           { 
             console.log("client")
            client.emit("room", { lines:  textToSend.toString("utf-8").split("\n") });  };
      });
    }
  
    fsTimeout = setTimeout(function() { fsTimeout=null }, 5000)}
    
    }
    
    
  );
});
```

In the above code I have added 2 clients,1 page is `index.html` and other is `client.html` and both are opening in the browser and getting connected to the socket but the data is not transmitting to any of them.Here's are my client codes:

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Websockets tail Server</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
  <div id="info" class="trebuchet"></div>
  <div id="tail" class="monospace selection"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var lines = 0, notice = $("#info"), buffer = $('#tail');
      var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/');
      socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('Connected to stream');
      });
  
  
      socket.on('room', function(msg) {
        console.log("Message:");
        console.dir(msg);
        buffer.append(msg.lines.join('<br/>'));
        buffer.scrollTop(lines*100);
        lines = lines + msg.lines.length;
      });
  
    })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`client.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Websockets tail Server</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
  <div id="info" class="trebuchet"></div>
  <div id="tail" class="monospace selection"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var lines = 0, notice = $("#info"), buffer = $('#tail');
      var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/');
      socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('Connected to stream');
      });
  
  
      socket.on('tail', function(msg) {
        console.log("Message:");
        console.dir(msg);
        buffer.append(msg.lines.join('<br/>'));
        buffer.scrollTop(lines*100);
        lines = lines + msg.lines.length;
      });
  
    })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Both the `html` files above are my clients and I want them to listen to my socket server but they are not but when I remove one of the clients,it works.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: A filewatch is being setup for every connection and the useful parts are being protected if `fsTimeout` has been set by any connection in the last 5 seconds

Comment: Can you describe what you want the socket stream to do? As it stands it watches for any fs event, then sends out an every increasing buffer of all previous file contents out to only the first connection, and only does all that if it's been more than 5 seconds since the last send ?